# Installing/upgrading/uninstalling packages using git

Tags: git, github

If I'm wanting to use a git package/script like [mutt-kz](https://github.com/karelzak/mutt-kz), what's the proper way (using git) to

1. Install it (I've been using 'git clone'; not sure if that's optimal)
2. Update it (no idea)
3. Uninstall it ('rm -r git-repo-dir/' ?)

I've skimmed a few git resources but they all seem to be aimed at those contributing to projects, which I'm not. I'm looking only to use the packages/scripts as though I installed them with apt/yum and then update them whenever I see the author has pushed a new commit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic answer, since the workflow usually depends on what the repo maintainer specified, but in general:

1. `git clone` to install is fine
2. `git pull` to update the repo usually works, unless you want to check the updates before you merge them, in which case you should `git fetch`. There's good info on `fetch` vs `pull` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)
3. `rm -rf`ing the repo directory should work to remove the repo (of course, anything you built will need to be removed separately)